# grails update favourites onclick

Tags: grails

I am looking for way to set up myFavorite table where onclick of list item i want to save it to myFavorite.

here I have

```
class user {  
    static hasMany [favorite : Favorite]
}

class Favorite {
    //(no fields) just the two static's below
    static belongsTo [user :user]
    static hasMany [music : Music]
}

static constraints = {
    id bindable: true 
    //id generator:'assigned'
    user unique: true
    music nullable: true
}
```

the aim is to keep one favorite.id per person and add music under the same id.

here is my controller

```
def save() {
    def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
    def principal = springSecurityService.principal

    int userid = principal.id // id of the person logged in
    def favorits = new Favorite(params) // form data
    def check = Favorite.findByUsers(authenticatedUser) // check if myFavorite exist for user
    def ids = check.id // id of the myFavorite
    def tracks = check.tracks.id + favorits.tracks.id

    def test2 = new Favorite(id:ids, 'users': userid, 'tracks': tracks)

    if (check == null){// if user don't have Favorite create one
        authenticatedUser.addToFavorite(favorits)
        authenticatedUser.save flush: true

    }

    //render([test2] as JSON)
    //test2.save flush: true
    update(test2)
}
```

the "test2.save flush: true" works  but it create new Favorite.ID instand of updateing the id i am passing.

Update(test2) also create a new id insted of updateing id i am passing.

Comment: If you need only one favourite per user why dont you use the hasOne instead the hasMany?

Comment: instead def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username) write: def user = springSecurityService.currentUser

Comment: And how you write it isn't grails style

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
def test2 = new Favorite(id:ids, 'users': userid, 'tracks': tracks)
```

You're creating a brand new `Favourite` instance here. If you want to update an existing `Favourite`, you need to retrieve the existing instance from your database and then make changes to that. Try something like this:

```
def test2 = Favourite.get(ids) //get the existing favourite by id
test2.users = ...              //update some properties
test2.save()
```